# Initialize Object in C# from DataGridView

Tags: c#, api, rest, object

I'm trying to Initialize an object using Datagridview to use it later in API POST.

Object

```
 public class StreamsPOSTModel
    {

        public class Fields
        {
            [JsonProperty("URL")]
            public string URL { get; set; }
        }

        public class Record
        {
            [JsonProperty("fields")]
            public Fields Fields { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            [JsonProperty("records")]
            public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My approach to Initialize it

```
 StreamsPOSTModel.Root newURL = new StreamsPOSTModel.Root
                {
                     
                };
```

Edit:
I tried this

```
StreamsPOSTModel.Root newURL = new StreamsPOSTModel.Root();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        StreamsPOSTModel.Record MyURL = new StreamsPOSTModel.Record();
                        MyURL.Fields.URL = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        newURL.Records.Add(MyURL);
                    };
```

but I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object on this line

```
 MyURL.Fields.URL = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Most likely at least one row has a null Value in Cells[1]. You can't call ToString() on null.

Comment: If you are reporting the correct line and it is not the cell values then it must be MyURL.Fields that is null. Are you not able to debug the code?

Comment: @Crowcoder
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() return a value just fine it reports null from MyURL.Fields.URL

Comment: The way you initialize `newUrl` does not initialize its `Records` property so it, and its `Fields` and so on are all null. Peter's low effort answer gives you a piece of the solution which is to initialize the objects in the constructors

Comment: @Crowcoder
MyURL.Fields.URL is null how do I fix it since I'm trying to give it a value to work in the first place?

Comment: @Crowcoder
I have already added the Root() from Peters code from the beginning, but I'm totally lost in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StreamsPOSTModel
{

    public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty("URL")]
        public string URL { get; set; }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        [JsonProperty("fields")]
        public Fields Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Root()
        {
            Records = new List<Record>();
        }
        [JsonProperty("records")]
        public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this helps me to Initialize my object

Comment: When you instantiate your class, the inner collection will not be null.